# btc-e.com parsing page (php)

Tags: php, curl

Try parse page (https://btc-e.com/) use this script, but always see how refresh page without any result...

My code

```
<?php
$hostname = 'btc-e.com';
$ch = curl_init('https://'.$hostname.'/index.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://'.$hostname.'/index.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_exec ($ch);
$result = curl_multi_getcontent ($ch);
echo "\n".'Login OK'."\n".'[result >'."\n".$result."\n".'<===>8=== result]'."\n";
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Result look like this :

> Login OK [result > HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: cloudflare-nginx Date: Sun,
>   01 Dec 2013 17:32:33 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Set-Cookie:
>   __cfduid=dd12eb0594d95f8b8a4dce4f7ec8af3771385919152984; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.btc-e.com; HttpOnly Expires:
>   Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache CF-RAY:
>   d61847227590835 Please wait...

Whats wrong ?

Comment: The web site is broken. It requires JavaScript to display any sort of content at all.

Comment: Why don't you use their API?

Comment: Also, why are you using, curl_multi_getcontent ($ch); ? You are not downloading more than one URL? This also looks like it could cause issues:

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));

Comment: I solved this problem. They use crafty redirect. They set one of need cookies via js and then do redirect to site. Firebug help me. Thx.